# How to detect the presence of a <script> tag with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a script tag on the page with content var x = 'test';. If I view the page source, the content is definitely there.

However I cannot get capybara to recognise this.
I've tried:

```
expect(page).to have_content("<script>var x = 'test';</script>")

expect(page).to have_content("var x = 'test';")

expect(page).to have_content("<script>")

find(:xpath, "//script")
```

None of these work and I'm out of ideas...

Comment: Try `expect(Capybara.string(response.body).gsub('\\', '').html_safe).to have_text("var x = 'test';")`

Comment: This gives:
 `undefined method body for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 2):

have_content (and its alias have_text) is for checking the text content of elements, not for checking for elements in the page.  You want to be using have_selector. If you're checking for at least one script element in the page it would be

```
expect(page).to have_selector(:css, 'script', visible: false, minimum: 1)
```

if checking for exactly one script element you could do

```
expect(page).to have_selector(:css, 'script', visible: false, count: 1)
```

obviously you can adjust the count/minimum numbers, or use the maximum or between options.  The visible: false option is important since script elements are not visible on the page and therefore won't be found without it.

Comment: now you can directly use `has_css?` and make sure to use `visible: false` as seen above otherwise it always return false

Answer (score 0):

Try below code -

`script` tag with `src` attribute with `.js` file included.

```
all('script').find { |s| s[:src].match /.js$/ }.should_not be_nil
```

`script` tag with inner html javascript code,

```
all('script').find { |s| s[:src].nil? }.count.should_not be(0)
```

Comment: this doesn't work unfortunately.
`expected: not nil
got: nil`

Still says there are no script tags on the page despite there being over a dozen on the page that I can see.

Comment: try now, I have added the second case where you are trying inner html javascript code exists. try the second sample where it checks if script tag exists and not link to external javascript file.

Comment: `NoMethodError:
       undefined method count' for nil:NilClass`

The find is still returning nil i'm afraid..

Comment: script tags aren't visible; add something like `all('script', visible: false)`